# moving back and forth div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to create some moving div, actually remake one, so that div would move endlessly back and forth, here is the script:

```
function animate(px) {
    $('.download').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "-10px"
    });
}
```

Thanks for help! ;)

Comment: I think you should pass the parameter px instead of having a -10px fixeed, if you want to move it, no static value should be there. Still your question is unclear.

Comment: @marcgg, [it's not endless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306666/moving-back-and-forth-div/7306762#7306762)? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to add `position: relative` to the `#download` element before doing this:

```
var func = function() {
    $(".download").animate({"left": "-40px"}, 1000, function() { 
        $(this).animate({"left": "40px"}, 1000) 
    })

    setTimeout(func, 2000);
}

//Or remove setTimeout and use the following line instead:
//func(); setInterval(func, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you Dave! but it stops after two animations.

Comment: anyway, i managed it myself, just put `setTimeout(func, 2000);` inside the function

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you. Fixed and clarified a bit.